# Install VS2013 after installing vs2013 Trial

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have an installed and license Visual Studio 2012 on my machine. I installed the VS2013 Trial, which is Ultimate. I have purchased an upgrade license for VS2013 Pro but when I go thru the installation and put in the Key it tells me that it is invalid for this version.  How do I get it to work? Do I need to do a trial version uninstall? and then reinstall from the upgrade disk?

Comment: I think the versions are quite different with Professional, Ultimate, and Premium.  I am having issues with my VS2013 Pro through MPN so a little peeved with Microsoft at the minute.  However, I would just uninstall the 2013 Trial and install the Professional version.  Make sure you select professional:  http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs

Comment: For a company that makes some of the most sophisticated software in the world they sure do let the ball drop at times.